# Can I install Whole Home Surge Protector into two single pole breakers?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I know that Square D HEPD80 calls for installation into a dual pole breaker but I currently don't have a space that's close to the main lugs since the wires that go to those breakers are very short (they have been cut to just accommodate those breakers).

I know that Square D calls for the installation to be as close to the main lugs as possible thus I was wondering if I could piggy back the two black wires from Square D into each of the single pole 15A breakers that are currently closest to the main lugs?  The breakers are one on top of the other so they should cover both phases/sides of the panel since the panel is crisscross (Eaton Panel).

Why does Square D ask for a dual pole breaker?

Answer (score 2):

That's what happens when Mr. Snippy gets into a panel and makes all the wires "neat" for the inspector, *as if there were brownie points for that*.  **Hots *and* Neutral should be able to reach any space in the panel**, neutral because of GFCIs.

Simply extend the wires with wire nut splices - it's ugly (by Mr. Snippy's standards), but it's no big deal electrically.

Can you use two 1-pole breakers on a 120/240V load? No.  As someone who accidentally bought a bunch of 30A 1-poles that are practically useless, I've researched this at length.

The two-pole breaker is because you have 2 hots and a neutral powering a single device.  Also, you want the amperage of the breaker to be fairly large so the surge suppressor can do its job - 15A is smaller than I'd want.  You're talking about a $10 breaker either way, so just use the one they recommend in the labeling and instructions - which is 30A.  *And use an Eaton brand breaker (CH if your handles are Cutler Hammer beige, otherwise BR).  Do not use other random hardware store brands, no matter how much the clerk insists they'll fit.  That isn't brand loyalty, it's busbar compatibility).*

Comment: I agree, the reason they ask for double pole is there are protective devices across at off 240v protection and split for 120v protection on the higher end models, I have installed dozens of these and found the larger ones that require a 30 amp breaker last longer if in an "electricly noisy" area, the smaller ones end up failing from the ones same brand that I have installed FWIW.+

Comment: So can I use a dual single pole 15A as long as they are one below the other (i.e. separate poles?)

Comment: The instruction sheet for my Eaton surge protector recommends a 2-pole 50 A breaker.

Comment: @tempnexus Instructions **require** "appropriate 2-pole circuit breaker", which is consistent with NEC requirements for 2-pole breakers on 120/240V devices, which it is.  This is a $10 breaker so you aren't going to save a king's ransom here.